# Where to store IMG files, if path is in MongoDB?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, web-services

I want to understand where to store files e.g. jpg, png, etc. I have a MongoDB which will have a BSON Something like (below is JSON) :

```
"gallery": [
    "path to server",
    "path to server"
  ],
```

The Path should guide the system to select these files and display them in the HTML content.

Can somebody lead me in the right direction which system could be used best to link MongoDb (Cloud Atlas), Node.js and a server where these files would be stored?
Is there any limitation which I should be aware of and is there a simple way how to implement these?

I have tried to look for tutorials, but couldn't find one. Can someone if possible push me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store these files on your own server, and the size allowed to store image will be your limit.

Instead, there is several `object storage` service that allows you to store images and other files.
Like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls) or [OVH Cloud](https://www.ovhcloud.com/en-gb/public-cloud/object-storage/). It's paid services, but it's easy to scale and the service is more or less always availability.
For example on Amazon, it cost 0.023$ per GB per month.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am not keen to have my own server as I am not sure how big the project will grow from 1 gb to 1 TB, and don't want a dedicated server for that, although it would be easiere.. 0.023$ per GB sounds very cheap. Is there good literature regarding Amozon? 

Which language would be best to work to upload data to Amazon? Is it compatible in working with Mongo DB (that may be a wrong question)

Comment: Yes it's not really expensive. The documentation is good and I think you can find some article and tutorial on how to upload a file. They have many SDK : Java, Python, PHP, node, so choose your favourite. I've only tried python. And yes no problems with mongo. It's a separate service so you send the files to Amazon,  they gave you back on id or an URL that can you save in your database as a string.

Comment: Thank You AlexisG, will try this out. At least a place where to start!